# spreadsheet script running with trigger and manually

Tags: google-apps-script

This should be simple but I'm stuck on this script...
It has a function (createnewsheet) that runs manually **AND** on a time trigger so I had to choose `openById()` to access the spreadsheet but when I'm looking at the sheet and run the function manually I want to set the newly created sheet active and that's what is causing me trouble.

When I run the function (createnewsheet) from the script editor everything is fine but when I call it from the spreadsheet menu I get this error message : `Specified sheet must be part of the spreadsheet` because of the last line of code.  AFAIK I'm not addressing a sheet outside my spreadsheet...  *Any idea what I'm doing wrong in this context ?*

Here is a simplified code that shows the problem, a [shared copy is available here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGVtYk5hWUZVUFNZMzAteE9DOUZwaVE)

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnqSFd3iikE3dGVtYk5hWUZVUFNZMzAteE9DOUZwaVE');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('master')
  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName('logger')
  var FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";

function onOpen() {
    var menuEntries = [ {name: "Manual test", functionName: "createnewsheet"},
                       ];
    sheet.addMenu("Utilities",menuEntries);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(logsheet);// this is working fine
    }

function createnewsheet(){

    var sheetName = "Control on "+ Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")
      try{ 
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName,2);// creates the new sheet in 3rd position
      }catch(error){
        FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
        var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName+' - '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH:mm:ss"),2);// creates the new sheet with a different name if already there
        }
    newsheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(sheetName);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);// should make 3 rd sheet active but works only when run from script editor
//    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(newsheet);// should have same result but works only when run from script editor
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a practical workaround to solve my use case : I use a different function from the menu (in wich I `setActive()` the sheet I want) and call the main function from this one.
When called from the trigger there is no use to set any active sheet so I removed this part from the main function.

It goes like this :

```
function manualTest(){ // from the ss menu
    createnewsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[2]);// this works from the menu when ss is open
}

function createnewsheet(){ // from the trigger and from function manualTest()
    var sheetName = "Control on "+ Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy");
      try{ 
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName,2);
      }catch(error){
        FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
        var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName+' - '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH:mm:ss"),2);
        }
    newsheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(sheetName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a catch here

```
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);
```

When you run it from script editor, It automatically gets the container spreadsheet and makes the said sheet active, but it is not the case when you run it from Custom Menu or triggers.
Modify this statement to:

```
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);
ss.setActiveSheet(newsheet);
```

Comment: Thanks for paying attention but this solution doesn't work for what I want : it has no effect on the UI when the spreadsheet is open. What I wanted is to be able to get the sheet 'active' when I manually run the function.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a bug introduced when the Google spreadsheet UI was updated. Earlier this used to work. Sorry for not testing the code before posting.

Comment: no worries ;-) Meanwhile I found a way to make it work...see edit

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i have found is to reseed `sheet`. `getActiveSpreadsheet()` recognises the Spreadsheet currently in use so no need to openById once more, but

```
//  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);
//  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(newsheet);
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // reloads the active sheet (including changes to the Sheets array)
sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[2]); // works as expected from editor and custom menu
```

I think this suggests that the original `ss` and `sheet` have cached the Spreadsheet to memory and their pointer isn't refreshed to reflect structural changes. I tried .flush() as a shortcut, but that seems a one way refresh to the sheet from the script, not the other way around.

Comment: which is effectively a shortcut to your two function solution - the key is the reallocation of `sheet` to the active sheet